# Sitecore search boosting

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-lucene

I have an index that is set to index my site components and pages.
I need to use field boosting for fields like Title, Description or Name. I've set in templates a boosting value 150, 100, and 50. If I search something that is only in Title, it does not boost the page in search ranking.

If I set the boosting on the component where the search word is found it gets boosted to the first position. After I delete the boosting form the component the search results does not change.

For search I'm using GetQueryable from IProviderSearchContext. 
How should I should set those templates so when I index the components I will get the pages as expected per boosting?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to boost fields, but that should not be done in the templates but in your configuration.

You can read all about it in this [John West blog](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-six-types-of-search-boosting.aspx).

For field boosting:

> You can boost the importance of specific fields. For example, you may
>   want to boost the value of specific fields, such as title or abstract.
>   Field boosting applies at indexing time, making it efficient but
>   static. Set the boost attribute of the relevant
>   /configuration/sitecore/contentSearch/configuration/DefaultIndexConfiguration/fieldMap/fieldNames/fieldName
>   element in the Web.config file, typically specified in the
>   /App_Config/Include/Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config
>   Web.config include file. All indexes share this configuration by
>   default.

He mentions the default index config here, but you can set it for your custom index just the same.

Comment: I've add a line into DefaultIndexConfiguration.config like bellow but the result did not got busted. Where 100f is the biggest value in the config file. <field fieldName="pageTitle"            storageType="No"  indexType="TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="100f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />

Comment: Can you share some more info (config, code, search log, Luke results...) on what you are trying and how you are testing the result?

Comment: I've looked in luke and the scoring for the documents seems to change if I change the "boost value" field but somehow the GetQueryable does not get the results order by score

Comment: So your index is correct (the boost is working), but the query is not giving the same results as you get in Luke? Can you share the query code and maybe also check your search logs to see what query is executed and compare with what you are testing in Luke.